# unable to set up lwjgl for eclipse on ubuntu

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, ubuntu-14.04, lwjgl

hey am trying to setup lwjgl for eclipse on ubuntu and i am having some problems need help i have added the lwjgl jar to the build path and poited it to the native folder but no luck when i try to run the test code provided on the site i get this error

[image]

here is the code

```
import org.lwjgl.*;
import org.lwjgl.glfw.*;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.*;

import static org.lwjgl.glfw.Callbacks.*;
import static org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW.*;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.*;
import static org.lwjgl.system.MemoryUtil.*;

public class HelloWorld {

// The window handle
private long window;

public void run() {
    System.out.println("Hello LWJGL " + Version.getVersion() + "!");

    try {
        init();
        loop();

        // Free the window callbacks and destroy the window
        glfwFreeCallbacks(window);
        glfwDestroyWindow(window);
    } finally {
        // Terminate GLFW and free the error callback
        glfwTerminate();
        glfwSetErrorCallback(null).free();
    }
}

private void init() {
    // Setup an error callback. The default implementation
    // will print the error message in System.err.
    GLFWErrorCallback.createPrint(System.err).set();

    // Initialize GLFW. Most GLFW functions will not work before doing this.
    if ( !glfwInit() )
        throw new IllegalStateException("Unable to initialize GLFW");

    // Configure our window
    glfwDefaultWindowHints(); // optional, the current window hints are already the default
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_VISIBLE, GLFW_FALSE); // the window will stay hidden after creation
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GLFW_TRUE); // the window will be resizable

    int WIDTH = 300;
    int HEIGHT = 300;

    // Create the window
    window = glfwCreateWindow(WIDTH, HEIGHT, "Hello World!", NULL, NULL);
    if ( window == NULL )
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed to create the GLFW window");

    // Setup a key callback. It will be called every time a key is pressed, repeated or released.
    glfwSetKeyCallback(window, (window, key, scancode, action, mods) -> {
        if ( key == GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE && action == GLFW_RELEASE )
            glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, true); // We will detect this in our rendering loop
    });

    // Get the resolution of the primary monitor
    GLFWVidMode vidmode = glfwGetVideoMode(glfwGetPrimaryMonitor());
    // Center our window
    glfwSetWindowPos(
        window,
        (vidmode.width() - WIDTH) / 2,
        (vidmode.height() - HEIGHT) / 2
    );

    // Make the OpenGL context current
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    // Enable v-sync
    glfwSwapInterval(1);

    // Make the window visible
    glfwShowWindow(window);
}

private void loop() {
    // This line is critical for LWJGL's interoperation with GLFW's
    // OpenGL context, or any context that is managed externally.
    // LWJGL detects the context that is current in the current thread,
    // creates the GLCapabilities instance and makes the OpenGL
    // bindings available for use.
    GL.createCapabilities();

    // Set the clear color
    glClearColor(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

    // Run the rendering loop until the user has attempted to close
    // the window or has pressed the ESCAPE key.
    while ( !glfwWindowShouldClose(window) ) {
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT); // clear the framebuffer

        glfwSwapBuffers(window); // swap the color buffers

        // Poll for window events. The key callback above will only be
        // invoked during this call.
        glfwPollEvents();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new HelloWorld().run();
}

}
```

picture of project hierarchy

[image]

and build path image

[image]

Answer (score 0):

LWJGL requires Java 8 or higher from the latest nightly builds on. The jar you downloaded has been compiled with JDK 8, which uses a file format version that is not supported by Java 7 JREs.

On Ubuntu you can install the `openjdk-8-jdk` package, although if you are using Ubuntu 14.04 you will have to use a PPA or alternative package since [OpenJDK 8 is not available there](https://askubuntu.com/questions/464755/how-to-install-openjdk-8-on-14-04-lts).